# Hide Arrows in Calendar view

Tags: style.css

I need to be able to hide the arrows above a calendar, but maintain the month and year. I found this style, but it takes both the arrows and the month/year out.

```
<style>
.ms-acal-header{
 display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-acal-header td:nth-child(-n+2) {
display:none;
}
</style>
```